# How to declare that the method's argument implements specific trait

Tags: rust

Can't understand that I am doing wrong:

```
pub trait HasName {
    fn name() -> String;
}

pub struct WorkerHandler<T: HasName> {
    arg: T,
}

impl<T: HasName> WorkerHandler<T> {
    pub fn run(arg: T) {
        println!("{}", arg.name());
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

This causes the error:

```
error: no method named `name` found for type `T` in the current scope
         println!("{}", arg.name());
                            ^~~~~~
```

The real case is a bit more complex, but I wish to explain to `run` that `T` implements `HasName` trait.

Answer (score 7):

Because you have defined an *associated function*, not a method — there is no `self` parameter.

Either you want

```
fn run(arg: T) {
    println!("{}", T::name());
}
```

or you want

```
trait HasName {
    fn name(&self) -> String;
}
```

Both are valid concepts representing different things. For example, an associated function would be useful for constructors. The [`Default` trait](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/default/trait.Default.html) is a good example of this.

Answer (score 2):

Your `name` method needs a `self` parameter:

```
pub trait HasName {
    fn name(&self) -> String;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works on simplified example.
I will try to applay to real and I will update if this approach will fail.